# Versioning with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'd like to get peoples thoughts on a scenario I'm about to encounter.

I've been tasked with building a RESTful Web API Service that will be used by two client applications.

One client application will be a web application and the other client will be a mobile application.

They are two distinctly different applications that are targeting the same data-store. I imagine that a lot of the requests made by both client applications will be of shared interest.(They may want to receive slightly different messages back in terms of the model objects they request).

But ultimately there will be differences, and I don't want to expose parts of the service that are designed for an individual client app to all other clients.

I've been looking at Versioning with ASP.NET Web API, where i can create the same controllers multiple times and create custom constraints to controller selectors that switch out the controller depending on the version used in the URI.

Is this a good idea in my scenario, or should i really be building two API's, one for each specific client application?

Comment: If they may receive **slightly** different returns, you can create 2 actions, or maybe an additional argument in your controllers methods..

Comment: Based on component based model, I would say 2 different Endpoints would be better. The switch based on the URI version will definitely have a latency as it basically runs through and if statement to check whether it matches the expected condition or not. On the other end, 2 different end points are straight forward, and will have no latency. Even though the latency is pretty small and invisible, with amount of N request it could go up to O(N)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want client A to access certain resources while client B shouldn't, you're going to implement authorization like [OAuth2](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server).

In the other hand, I doubt that the solution should be implementing 2 different APIs or overcomplicate the code of a single API to return the same response with some differences.

Furthermore, you can emit same DTO for both clients and map the *generic DTO* to a domain object or other DTO using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) in order to avoid the hassle to manually set properties from one object to the other.

Finally, you can also use an [OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) interface to your RESTful API to let the client decide which properties you want to return in your entities or perform other operations during the request and get just what you need in each case.

**Conclusion/summary**: you shouldn't adapt the REST API to your clients, but the clients should adapt themselves to how the API works. At the end of the day, you're returning JSON entities and you can map them to any class even if the structure is different using AutoMapper as I said in the first paragraph. You can even implement a custom serializer if needed. It will be less pain than duplicating the server code because some differences.

What would happen if you add a third client and says "I want also a different structure in returned entities", add even a fourth one! You're going to get crazy, aren't you?

Comment: Thanks for this, great advice.